# MPI_send как сделать циклический сдвиг числа на +1

Tags: c, распараллеливание, mpi

В каждом процессе дано целое число. С помощью функций MPI_Send и MPI_Recv осуществить для всех процессов циклический сдвиг данных с шагом 1, переслав число из процесса 0 в процесс 1, из процесса 1 в процесс 2, …, из последнего процесса в процесс 0. В каждом процессе вывести полученное число.

```
    int flag;
    MPI_Initialized(&flag);
    if (flag == 0)
        return;
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Status s;
    int n;
    pt >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        MPI_Send(&n,1,MPI_INT,i,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто используете в качестве процесса получателя для MPI_Send значение +1 по модулю размера коммуникатора, а процесс отправитель для MPI_Recv можно по обратной формуле вычислить:

```
MPI_Send(&n, 1, MPI_INT, (i + 1) % size, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MPI_Recv(&n, 1, MPI_INT, (size + (i - 1)) % size, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

Comment: Насчет MPI_Send(), я так и думал, точнее думал но не написал, а вот с Recv мне немного не понятно.

Comment: не могу понять откуда там 4, для чего.

Comment: теперь я понял, 4 это общий size

Comment: Блин, сорри, да, это общий size конечно, я пока выводил формулу на своём примере в ответ это значение машинально записал :)
Обновил ответ.